# Spring-Boot-Actuator Endpoint Prometheus not shown correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I want to show some metrics using micrometer prometheus in combination with the spring-boot-actuator. My project is totally based on spring-boot and has the actuator feature enabled and mapped on the following url: http://localhost:9000/actuator
Other endpoints are shown correctly but the http://localhost:9000/actuator/prometheus isn´t. Below you find a screenshot that I get when accessing this http-endpoint.

Can anybody help me? Why is this happening and how do i fix it?
Cause normally prometheus is configured automatically for spring-boot-actuator when you provide the suitable dependency.

[image: Blank space when i try to access the url: http://localhost:9000/actuator/prometheus]

[image: Accessing http://localhost:9000/actuator leads to the following and shows that prometheus endpoint is activated and exposed]

Comment: Try running your application with the `--debug` flag (or `-Ddebug`). From the given information, it seems like some autoconfiguration is not being done. Enabling debug will tell you exactly why (either missing dependency, wrongly configured properties, etc.).

Comment: thanks for the reply but it didnt log out anything usefull, just normal stuff while starting the application, any further ideas?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the prometheus' configuration? Make sure that the metrics_path is configured correctly e.g metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'

Comment: prometheus configuration? is this necessary? cause i thought there is /actuator/prometheus configured per default 
can you provide me a example config? would be very helpful=)

Answer (score 4):

you need to check many things to be sure to enable Prometheus by Actuator

- First thing you should put the following dependency on your `pom.xml` to enable Prometheus on your project.

  ```
           <!-- enable prometheus-->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
           <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
           <version>1.10.2</version>
       </dependency>
  ```
- The second point you must check if the actuator exists on your
  project or not if doesn't exist, you need to add the following
  dependency.

  ```
       <!--to enable actuator help to trace project-->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
   </dependency>
  ```
- You need to add the following scripts to your application.yml to
  enable the actuator and Prometheus by actuator.

.

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  server:
    port: 9000
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: always
      show-components: always
      probes:
        enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
    info:
      env:
        enabled: true
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus, metrics, info, health, shutdown, beans
```

using the above script the actuator will run on **port 9000** and you can send a request to the following URL to access the actuator.

**http://localhost:9000/actuator/prometheus**

**and the following URL to access Prometheus**

http://localhost:9000/actuator/prometheus

**Note**: you must check where you are writing your script because I was confused between **endpoint** and **endpoints**

- The **endpoint** to set the actuator config.
- The **endpoints** to set the actuator **URLs endpoint**

**Note:** you can delete the port from  `application.yml` and the actuator will run by current application port

**best luck**

Comment: fyi: the Micrometer team does not recommend defining versions in case you use Spring Boot (or something else that defines Micrometer versions). Also, I'm not sure why you define so many properties in your yaml file when you only need one.

Answer (score 1):

This is auto-cofigured by default, here are some pointers for troubleshooting:

- Check if you added `micrometer-registry-prometheus` (without defining the version, the version should come from the BOM)
- Check if the actuator endpoint is enabled: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`
- Check if there is a controller that maps the path of the prometheus endpoint or any of its sub-paths (`/`, `/actuator`, `/actuator/prometheus`)
- Check if you browser tricks you `curl localhost:9090/actuator/prometheus`

Comment: the only path mapped here is the context path of the application to / but it doenst effect the other endpoints
interesting to mention is that the /metrics endpoint shows all metrics but not values for them
maybe there is a relation between the 2 problems? but i cannot think of it why

Comment: Thank you. The `without defining the version` part was what got this working for me.

Answer (score 0):

to me , this did the trick, with everything else enabled ( endpoints and metrics ) but without this, /actuactor/prometheus was not exposed

```yaml
management:
  metrics: 
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score -1):

ok i solved it with the solution:

i created a bean of type prometheusMeterRegistry manually and so spring boot didn't configure it automatically leading to no metrics provided at the prometheus endpoint
see below code snippet for further details:

```java
// @Bean
// public PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusMeterRegistry() {
//  return new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
// }
```

Comment: fyi: this is only hiding the real problem, Spring Boot autoconfigures this, check if you have spring-boot-actuator and the versions are matching.

Comment: which versions do you mean? all spring boot versions are checked and consistent
and just updated to spring-boot 2.6 and used the matching version of prometheus for this

Comment: You need to add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus`, no version, the version should come from the BOM. The Spring Boot auto-config must create a PrometheusMeterRegistry for you (registered in a composite). If it does not, please create an issue for Spring Boot.

Comment: I think here is the bug lurking somethere. Because I have the same issue with Spring Boot 2.6. Actuator just ingnore Prometheus existance

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was trying to set up prometheus on old project where was `MetricsAutoConfiguration` excluded. So removing exclude solved the problem.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
```